# Endpoints Bad Api Configuration

Tags: google-app-engine

I am having a weird issue with endpoints, and I don't have a clue where to start looking to solve the problem.

```
Endpoints: https://mysite/_ah/api/myEclipseGeneratedEndpoint@v1 

Error: Bad API configuration: Schema type must be 'any', 'array', 'object', or 'string'.
```

I am getting the above error. The this happens with 2 out of three of my endpoints. The strange thing is on the latest upload that caused this issue, I did not alter the endpoints. The code I did add did not even interact with the datastore that the endpoints are linked to.

All three of my endpoints have not been altered in any way in weeks, yet two start failing. I'm not sure what to make of this. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Same problem here. Any light on this would be appreciated.

Comment: I've got the same problem :(

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10146 - I've filed a defect issue.

Comment: I don't have a solution, yet. I was actually to just making sure it wasn't some mistake on my part. I am about to try to roll back to an older version of GAE. I'll post the results.

Comment: @Pinsickle Please let us know the result of the roll back.  But the app engine servers are running 1.8.6 App Engine Release.  Is there a way to roll back on production?  I don't believe so.

Comment: Yeah you are right. You can't roll back. I had the 1.8.5 SDK, I tried updating to the latest version but it hasn't made a difference.

Comment: @Pinsickle I tried the same here.  it was 4 days ago that 1.8.6 was featured at  https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/downloads from the site:  appengine-java-sdk-1.8.6.zip  Google App Engine SDK for Java 1.8.6   Featured  4 days ago  4 days ago

Comment: Seems like the issue has been accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in AppEngine - see https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10146

But anyway, this service proved its unreliability. Do you know some good alternative? (Mainly for mobile clients' code generation for your backend API written in Java.)

Answer (score 0):

I had defined primary key to be of type **Key** in my Entity class as follows:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Key id;
```

I changed it to **Long** (also tried **String**) and the error seems to be gone:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

However, this would still be a problem for a child entity as it needs to have `Key` as the primary key type.

Comment: Just out of curiosity I added the GeneratedValue annotation, but it didn't make a difference for me.

Comment: What is the type of you `id` field?

Comment: I am using the String type.

Comment: Is there any field that is using `Key` type?

Comment: No, there is not. All three of my Entity classes use Strings for ids. Which makes it even more strange that only two of them stopped working